# What is meant by varjyam? What are the consequences of born in it?

Tags: astrology

How is varjyam calculated and is there any scientific reason behind it.
When a child is born in varjyam it is told as a bad sign.
If it is right what are the problems faced by the child in life

Comment: What has the photograph to do with your question? Also try to make the question more clear what are you asking?

Comment: Thyajyam is an inauspicious time of the day during which it's   generally suggested not to do /start any auspicious work  like buying/entering new house , buying new goods ,Naming of child etc. It looks like from primary search that this has nothing to do with birth.

Comment: It is Rahukalam or inauspicious period  for undertaking no new works.. so must be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

Varjyam is a Dur-muhurta or inauspicious time of the day. It occurs everyday based on the nakshatra. It is calculated based on small portion of degrees of every star (nakshatra). The timings are easily available in the panchagams.

> Nakshatra Thyajyam is quite significant in Tamil Astrology. Nakshatra
>   Thyajyam is an inauspicious time of approximately 1 hour and 36
>   minutes every day. No auspicious Muhurtam is suggested during this
>   time window. Many Panchang, including Drik Panchang, shows Nakshatra
>   Thyajyam as Varjyam in daily Panchangam. Nakshatra Thyajyam is known
>   as Visha Ghatis in North India.
>
> **Prohibited Activities** Marriage, Chudakaram (Mundan), Annaprasana Samskara, entering into new house, travelling, any other auspicious
>   work should be avoided during Nakshatra Thyajyam.
>
> **Synonyms** Varjyam, Visha Ghatis, Vishagatika, Visha Nadi, Vishanadi
>   Dosha, Nakshatra Tyajyam, Nakshatra Thyajya, Nakshatra Thiyajam

[Panchanga](http://www.drikpanchang.com/tutorials/panchang-utilities/nakshatra-thyajyam.html)

However, there is no specific mention related to birth in this time. If you still want to get some remedial measures performed then you can contact your local priest for the same.

Comment: It's pretty obvious that there would be no mention of birth in all this. Anyone could take birth at any time irrespective of auspicious time or inauspicious time and priest can do nothing about it. A person has to go through their prarabdha irrespective of birth time.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria obvious comment..